# Einordnung von Verbalkomplexen

Tags: verb-usage

Ich habe mich mit Verbalkomplexen beschäftigt und bin etwas verwirrt über die für mich teilweise willkürlich erscheinende Einteilung in lexikalische und grammatikalisierte Komplexe.

Es gibt eindeutig grammatikalisierte Komplexe, wie etwa das Perfekt.
Es gibt eindeutig lexikalische Komplexe, wie etwa "ich gehe Schwäne füttern"; es ist deutlich, dass jemand geht und Schwäne füttert, d. h., eine Deutung als Analogon zum going to-Futur ist unzulässig.

Dann gibt es z. B. das Rezipientenpassiv - "Ich bekomme die Haare geschnitten" - in denen das zum Hilfsverb degradierte finite Verb sehr nah an der Bedeutung des Vollverbs steht.

Auf der anderen Seite gibt es etwa "Ich pflege Schwäne zu füttern", bei dem das finite Verb absolut nichts mit der Bedeutung des Vollverbs zu tun hat (zumindest nicht mehr), und dennoch gilt es als ein lexikalischer Komplex ("Halbmodal", Zifonun) anstatt etwa als Habitual.

Ich verstehe die Logik dahinter nicht. Wieso etwa wird "pflegen zu" nicht als grammatikalisiertes Habitual angesehen?

Comment: Hast du noch ein anderes Beispiel, was dir aufstößt oder nur konkret das?

Comment: Vielleicht spielt die zeitliche Komponente hier eine Rolle. Wenn man etwas zu tun pflegt, beinhaltet das keine konkrete Aussage über den Zeitpunkt. Eventuell verhält es sich so bei regelmäßigen Handlungen/ Gewohnheiten, usw..

Comment: ich pflege ungepflegt herumzulaufen ... :))

Answer (score 3):

Gerade das erste Beispiel eignet sich dazu, sich über den Unterschied zwischen Bedeutung und grammatischer Funktion eines Verbs Gedanken zu machen.

> Ich bekomme die Haare geschnitten

geht von folgendem Bild aus, wenn wir den modernen Begriff von “bekommen” als “empfangen” zugrundelegen:

> Ich übergebe dem Friseur meine Haare zur Bearbeitung und bekomme sie geschnitten zurück.

Es ist zwar fraglich, ob das hier formulierte Bild “geben – bekommen – haben” wirklich die Grundlage dieser Wendung ist. Die Konstruktion “Ich bekomme die Haare geschnitten” lehnt sich an den Gebrauch von “bekommen” mit Adjektiv an, wie in “jemanden frei bekommen”, “etwas satt bekommen” und dann “etwas satt haben”, “jemanden lieb bekommen” (statt “gewinnen”, heute nicht mehr gebräuchlich) und dann “jemanden lieb haben”. “Bekommen” beschreibt also einen Vorgang von nicht von vornherein definierter Dauer und könnte somit als transitives Gegenstück zu “werden” gelten:

> Ich bekomme die Haare vom Friseur geschnitten
>
> Mir werden die Haare vom Friseur geschnitten

Doch für beide Interpretationen von “bekommen” kann man in der Folge zwei Begriffspaare bilden:

> bekommen -> haben
>
> werden -> sein

Danach, und hier liegt der Unterschied, sind meine Haare geschnitten,

> doch ich habe die Haare nicht geschnitten (so wie ich z.B. etwas *satt habe*), sondern der Friseur hat sie geschnitten, obwohl er ja meine Haare nicht “hat” (= besitzt).

Hier wechselt offensichtlich das Konzept. Auch die Verwendung des Hilfsverbs “haben” ist noch aus der lexikalischen Bedeutung “besitzen” erklärbar, doch ist daraus eine fixe Formel entstanden, die eine abgeschlossene Handlung in der Vergangenheit anzeigt:

> Der/die Handelnde + “hat” + Objekt + dem Objekt neu hinzugefügte Eigenschaft (Partizip)

Ich muss auch, was ich satt oder lieb habe, nicht besitzen, aber es ist möglich, genauso wie der Friseur fremde oder seine eigenen Haare schneiden kann. Er kann aber nur seine eigenen Haare geschnitten bekommen; die lexikalische Bedeutung von “bekommen” entscheidet also über die spezifische Verwendung des Verbs auch in einer unterstützenden, modalen Funktion. Die Grundbedeutung von “haben” schränkt die Verwendung als Hilfsverb lediglich auf die große Gruppe transitiver Verben ein.

Ebenso ist das Verb “werden” Hilfszeitwort für die Passivform in Ableitung von seiner Bedeutung:

> Der, mit dem etwas geschieht + “werden” + durch die Handlung neu hinzugefügte Eigenschaft (Partizip)

Die Passivform enthält noch eine deutliche Analogie zur propositionalen, selbstständigen Bedeutung von “werden” (sich zu etwas entwicklen, sich in etwas verwandeln). Denn “werden” ist von Haus aus keine Handlung des Subjekts, sondern etwas, dem das Subjekt unterworfen ist. Die Futurform hingegen entfernt sich von dieser Analogie. Sie besteht aus dem Hilfsverb und einem finalen Infinitiv:

> Ich werde essen.

Hier ist die Verbindung zwischen “werden” und “essen” primär durch die grammatische Konstruktion gegeben. Man könnte natürlich übersetzen in:

> Ich werde, um zu essen

was wenig sinnvoll ist, oder:

> Ich werde zu jemandem, der isst

Wobei das aktive Moment einer Handlung in der Zukunft verlorengeht. Anders ist es, wenn man ein Verb als “Umstandsverb” (Modalverb) verwendet, das Auskunft darüber gibt, unter welchen Umständen etwas geschehen wird:

> Ich gehe essen.
> Ich gehe Schwäne füttern.
> Ich gehe ins Restaurant.

“Gehen” statt “werden” gibt hier darüber Auskunft, dass die beabsichtigte bzw. zukünftige Handlung folgen wird, sobald die Handlung des Modalverbs “erfüllt” ist. Diese vorbereitende Handlung beginnt sofort und endet in der nahen Zukunft. Die Zukunftsform “Ich werde essen” enthält keine Information darüber, wann in der Zukunft die Handlung stattfinden wird; diese muss durch den Kontext gegeben werden. Intransitive Verben der Bewegung benützen den freien finalen Infinitiv zur Anzeige ihres Ziels. Bei Verben wie *wollen*, *können*, *dürfen*, *müssen* ist der finale Infinitiv fixer Bestandteil, weil sie eine Handlung als Objekt verlangen.

Bei den Hilfszeitwörtern “werden”, “sein” und “haben” sind die lexikalischen Bedeutungen zwar Grundlage für die grammatische Funktion, sie treten aber gegenüber der Gesamtbedeutung mehr oder weniger in den Hintergrund.

vgl. http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/gruwi.ansicht?v_id=1690

"Pflegen"+ "zu" + Infinitiv ist eine Konstruktion, die die Anwendung des ersten Verbs auf das nachfolgende anzeigt, wie auch bei *wissen*, *versuchen* etc. Nur die Grundstruktur ist hier grammatisch. Die Aussage wird lexikalisch durch beide Verben bestimmt:

> Ich pflege Schwäne zu füttern. Ich glaube Schwäne zu füttern. Ich versuche Schwäne zu füttern. Ich versuche Schwäne zu pflegen. **Aber:** Ich glaube Schwäne zu versuchen. Ich füttere Schwäne zu glauben.

Offenbar können sich manche Verben auf beiden Positionen befinden, die Regel ist dies aber nicht. Das liegt daran, dass das erste Verb auf einer anderen Aussageebene liegt und geeignet sein muss, ein bestimmtes Verhältnis zwischen Subjekt und der durch die Infinitivgruppe bezeichneten Handlung zu beschreiben.

Übrigens ist "etwas regelmäßig tun", "zu etwas neigen", "etwas gewohnt sein" mit der Kernbedeutung "sich um etwas kümmern" direkt verbunden, mit der Wendung "zu etwas sehen" vergleichbar, man pflegt etwas, nämlich eine Gewohnheit (vgl. pflegen/IV im [Grimm-Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GP04052)).

Comment: "werden" bildete mit "sein" das Paar Inchoativ/Verlaufsform; *ich werde essend" und "ich bin essend"; lexikalisch "Ich werde ein Essender" und "Ich bin ein Essender". Das -d entfiel, die Verlaufsform dann ebenfalls, erhob sich allerdings als Absentiv aus dem Grabe. Man beachte die wunderschöne Symmetrie zu Vorgangs- und Zustandspassiv.

Answer (score 1):

> **pflegen zu tun:** Man hat sich gedanklich beschäftigt mit der Methodik, (die nach persönlichem Ermessen beste Art und Weise ausgewählt) und sie sich zur Gewohnheit gemacht.

Demnach: Wenn man "pflegen" abstrakter sieht, dann passt auch der Satz "Ich pflege Schwäne zu füttern" = "Ich habe es mir zur Gewohnheit gemacht, Schwäne zu füttern."